# Does the V language allow to extend base types?

Tags: vlang

In V language methods are defined separately from the data structures.

Does the V language allow to define methods on base types, like `Array`?

Is it possible to write `my_method` method like

```
fn (array Array) my_method() { ... }

list := ["a", "b"]
list.my_method()
```

Comment: I don't believe so... I get `error: cannot define new methods on non-local `array_int`` when I try it.  Unlike Ruby, I guess we don't extend other module's data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only in your own modules were you control the implementation - and I don't think there's any plans to support it.

You might do something like it with either generics or struct embeds, when they're fully done. But I doubt there'll be support for it for `builtin` module types.

Edit:
(In the future it might also be possible to do something with Sum types)

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a method on a type unless the type and method are both defined in the same module. However you can define a method on an array of a custom type if both the method and the custom type are in the same module. For example:

```
struct St
{
    i int
}

fn (s []St) array_method() {
    println(s[0])
    println(s[1])
}

arr := [St{3}, St{4}]
arr.array_method()
```